# Has the accounting services industry ever been disrupted in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, finance, labour-history, business-history

What is the most-radical example of a disrupting service / model in the *accounting* business services industry?

What I mean by disrupted is that someone has at some point taken such a radically different approach, to deliver the same service that the old way of doing things was abandoned.

One comparable example (though not a business service):

> The invention of the electric light bulb. This was a technology, which
>   completely disrupted the lighting market. However, I assume that if
>   Thomas Edison would have walked around from house to house to and
>   attempted selling a light-bulb together with some sort of membership
>   in the local grid, then his marketing efforts would have failed
>   because they would not have believed that it was possible. His
>   advantage was that he could show people that it worked and thereby
>   immediately gaining trust.

Was there any time in U.S. history in which accounting/finance/banking took a sharp turn? Did this occur, for instance, during or as a result of the Great Depression? Was the collapse of the "Big Eight" accounting firms into the "Big Four" following the demise of Arthur Andersen such a watershed event?

Comment: Why the close votes

Comment: This question is only marginally related to history. On top of that, it seems to be soliciting lists, which is not what we try to do. On top of that, it's pretty broad overall. If you would like to try to modify it, we can keep it here. Otherwise I think I'd be inclined to go along with the votes to close it.

Comment: @StevenDrennon It's borderline...I'll stay neutral on this one. :)

Comment: @David To "disrupt the market" means to (temporarily) stop all the service buying/selling activity; for example if you'd convert accounting from a business-to-business service to a state-sponsored, government-regulated program. Instead, do you want to ask about business-to-business services which were revolutionized in the course of history, and in which marketing efforts played the main part? (Note they could have been revolutionized because of external causes, without any marketing)

Comment: @kubanczyk I have attempted to clarify the question now. I had not thought about markets getting disrupted by government intervention or similar. I was more thinking about disruptions happening "naturally" in a liberal market like the one I describe the last paragraph.

Comment: Seems more like you could look at the textiles market, if you think of industrialization removing the process of creating linens and other textiles from the "cottage manufacturers" its similar to a disruption you describe.

Comment: proposed changes to resolve the qualms, in hopes of a targeted historical scope.

Comment: @NewAlexandria Thank you for attempting to fix the question. Unfortunately, since we are now only getting examples from the accounting business, and not business services in general, I do not thing that I will get any answers that will help me in my case. I also do not believe that we will get any answers at all, since the service that this business delivers is a very traditional one.

Comment: I edited the question to give it a historical focus and added some historical examples, and nominate it for reopening in its edited form.

Comment: @TomAu I agree it is an interesting question, even if OP no long think so fo his purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1929 stock market crash (and the excesses, bordering on illegality that led to it) led to the creation of the Securities and Exchange Commission in 1934, following the onset of the Great Depression in the early 1930s.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Securities_and_Exchange_Commission

There were Congressional acts, those of 1933 and 1934 that changed the way that companies accounted for, and more importantly reported their financial results. The Act of 1933 dealt mainly with beefed up reporting requirements. The Act of 1934 established the Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC) to enforce the 1933 Act. It also gave the SEC to regulate the offering and sale of securities such as stocks and bonds. As such, the oversight of the SEC greatly reduced (although it did not totally eliminate) a number of "shady" practices perpetrated by companies and stock brokers on unsuspecting investors. As such, 1933-34 represents a watershed for corporate accounting to investors.

The reduction of the "Big 8" accounting firms to the "Big 4," culminating in the collapse of Arthur Andersen (earlier the fifth) in 2002, due to the Enron scandal, may have been the harbinger of the new 1930s. It created a shortage of "large" accounting behemouths, but contributed to the rise of a group of smaller, hopefully more effective accounting firms.

One book (written by yours truly) that discusses the original 1929 stock market crash, the 1930s Depression, and the possibility of a new crash (like the one that took place in 2008), and a possible return to the modern 1930s is [http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Approach-Graham-Investing-Finance/dp/0471584150/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471584150)

Answer (score 0):

The mass internal accounting structures which developed with modern firms in the 1930s and 1940s disrupted small manufacture, and radically changed the pool of accounting profession and labour opportunities.  So "the firm" as in the modern firm in Fordism, including its corresponding departmental structure in government, caused a rupture in the supply of accountancy services—but this happened under an increasing market for accounting services and was tied with increasing personal accounting complexity.

Similarly with the development of outsourced accounting specialist firms since the change in Fordism in the 1970s.  ( http://www.ey.com/GL/en/About-us/Our-people-and-culture/Our-history/About-EY---Key-Facts-and-Figures---History---Timeline )

Accountancy as a professional service is tied into firm and state-as-capitalist structures.

Accounting history is a specialist sub-area, normally supervised under academic accounting.  It is both quite productive, and quite exciting as a discipline, it deals with the formal subsumption of value: how production gets turned into profits.